# Add new tracking number to existing shipment using REST API

Tags: magento2, shipping, rest-api, shipment, shipment-tracking

How can I add a new tracking number to an already existing shipment that was created using the following endpoint [link](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.0-admin/tag/orderorderIdship) ?

I can create the shipment for a sale/order with the initial tracking number/s, but if I use the same endpoint from above to add a new tracking number for the same order/sale, I get the following error: "you can't create a shipment without products"

Which endpoint should I use? Is it one of these ([[1]](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.0-admin/tag/shipmenttrack), [[2]](https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.0-admin/tag/shipment#operation/salesShipmentRepositoryV1SavePost)) or some other? I am a beginner and magento-documentation is confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint did what I wanted https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1/salesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1SavePost